# Wunderground PHP

Tags: php, json

I've only just learnt a bit on JSON and I'm currently trying to show the temperature and weather condition using the weather underground API and PHP, I have the temperature showing up but not the weather status. Here is my code:

```
<?php
$json_string = file_get_contents("http://api.wunderground.com/api/9fca46f2c0517556/geolookup/conditions/q/UK/Leeds.json");
$parsed_json = json_decode($json_string);
$location = $parsed_json->{'location'}->{'city'};
$weather =$parsed_json->{'weather'};
$temp_c = $parsed_json->{'current_observation'}->{'temp_c'};
echo "Current temperature in ${location} is: ${temp_c}\n degrees and it is currently ${weather}";
?>
```

Comment: `var_dump($parsed_json)`, and see what you received. yes, you can prompt a user for whatever information you want, and then can use that information however you want.

Comment: All those curly braces are unnecessary, by the way. Object properties typically get referenced `$like->this` and variables can be included `"inside a $double quoted string"` without any problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot a node in your `$parsed_json` object access, replace :

```
$weather =$parsed_json->{'weather'};
```

With :

```
$weather = $parsed_json->current_observation->weather;
```

And more generaly use :

```
$json_string = file_get_contents("http://api.wunderground.com/api/9fca46f2c0517556/geolookup/conditions/q/UK/Leeds.json");
$parsed_json = json_decode($json_string);
$location = $parsed_json->location->city;
$weather =$parsed_json->current_observation->weather;
$temp_c = $parsed_json->current_observation->temp_c;
echo "Current temperature in ${location} is: ${temp_c}\n degrees and it is currently ${weather}";
```

Comment: Thankyou this worked!

Comment: Thanks, your welcome ! Don't forget to mark this question as solved :)

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A good answer will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: You'r right :) It's edited now !